# Alpine Linux unable to install hping; ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints

Tags: software-installation, alpine-linux

hping is available on Alpine.

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=hping3&arch=x86&repo=testing

However when I tried to install it, I'm getting the following error message.

```
localhost:~$ apk search -v hping
localhost:~$ sudo apk search -v hping
localhost:~$ 
localhost:~$ sudo apk add hping
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  hping (missing):
    required by: world[hping]
localhost:~$ 

localhost:~$ sudo apk add hping2
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  hping2 (missing):
    required by: world[hping2]
localhost:~$ 

localhost:~$ sudo apk add hping3
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  hping3 (missing):
    required by: world[hping3]
localhost:~$
```

I don't have this problem on other packages such as tcpdump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hping3` is in the testing repository.

```
# apk add hping3 --update-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

You can also add this repository to `/etc/apk/repositories`.

Comment: Thanks @user234931, it works.
However, all hping binary was compiled without TCL scripting support.

`localhost:/etc/apk$ hping
hping   hping2  hping3
localhost:/etc/apk$ hping
hping   hping2  hping3
localhost:/etc/apk$ hping3
Sorry, this hping binary was compiled without TCL scripting support
localhost:/etc/apk$ 

localhost:/etc/apk$ hping3 -v
hping version 3.0.0-alpha-1 ($Id: release.h,v 1.4 2004/04/09 23:38:56 antirez Exp $)
NO TCL scripting support compiled in
localhost:/etc/apk$`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread and I've enabled tcl for hping3 in Alpine Linux:

https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/commit/?id=e2234712acb3c0e00d14ccada2f576b2c746393c

Just add the new package with:

`apk add -X http://dl-dn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing hping3`

`hping3-20051105-r4` is the one having tcl enabled.

Francesco